# ViewState values for string array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, web

I need to store the values into an array which I already implemented. Sadly, only the latest value is stored on looping. I want all the values to be stored, I tried to use ViewState, but this code below is not working or getting me what I wanted. Please help me.

```
foreach loop
{
successBenefitCodes =  new [] {ben.BenefitCode.ToString()};
ViewState["successBenefitCodes"] = successBenefitCodes;
successBenefitCodes = ViewState["successBenefitCodes"] as string[];
}
```

Comment: Please clear your concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this.

```
    List<string> successBenefitCodes = new List<string>();
    foreach(var ben in youritems)
    {
    successBenefitCodes.Add(ben.BenefitCode.ToString());
    }
    ViewState["successBenefitCodes"] = successBenefitCodes.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks good, but I have this problem again: string message = String.Join(",", successBenefitCodes); I mean to say, I want to convert this list items into comma separated values and store in a string which is displayed as message in output

Comment: Do you want to store string or array of string ?

Comment: String.Join(",", successBenefitCodes.ToArray());

Comment: dotnetstep, thank you SO MUCH - You are the GOD :) QUickly resulted in what I want :) :) :) Cheers